# Encrypt string in JavaScript and decrypt in PHP with RSA technique

Tags: encryption, cryptography, php, javascript

I am trying to encrypt some text in JavaScript and then send it to PHP (etc: with Ajax) to decrypt it there and save it (etc: In MySQL).

Here is my code so far:

**In JavaScript:**

I am using this library for the encryption:
http://travistidwell.com/blog/2013/02/15/a-better-library-for-javascript-asymmetrical-rsa-encryption/

```
function ConvertToURL(data) {
    // Converts data to URL friendly form
    // etc: Replaces '+', '/', '=' with 'plus', 'slash', 'equal'
};
function AjaxOrder(data) {
    // Sends data in PHP with Ajax
}

var publicKey = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDlOJu6TyygqxfWT7eLtGDwajtN
FOb9I5XRb6khyfD1Yt3YiCgQWMNW649887VGJiGr/L5i2osbl8C9+WJTeucF+S76
xFxdU6jE0NQ+Z+zEdhUTooNRaY5nZiu5PgDB0ED/ZKBUSLKL7eibMxZtMlUDHjm4
gwQco1KRMDSmXSMkDwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----';

var encrypt = new JSEncrypt();
encrypt.setPublicKey(publicKey);
var encrypted = encrypt.encrypt('Text to send.');

*// And now I am sending the encrypted text with some Ajax function*

AjaxOrder(ConvertToURL(encrypted));
```

**In PHP:**

```
$dataPost = $_POST('dt');

function ConvertFromURL($data) {
    // Converts $data to original form
    // etc: Replaces 'plus', 'slash', 'equal' with '+', '/', '='
}
function ReturnData($data) {
    // Sends $data back in JavaScript as an answer to Ajax
}

$privateKey = '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----';

openssl_private_decrypt(ConvertFromURL($dataPost), $decryptedWord, $privateKey);

ReturnData(base64_encode($decryptedWord));
```

Now the answer from PHP is empty every time. Any ideas to make this work?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Just curious - what's the benefit of this?  If you're on a secure connection, snooping is impossible.  If you're on an *insecure* connection, then there is absolutely zero guarantee that you're running the right JavaScript.

Comment: Poor man's SSL... is actually SSL, because it's way less time-consuming than whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: There is no secure connection. I am trying to secure the transferred data over the internet and this way is more understandable for me. If you have a more secure or easy way I am hearing.. :)

Comment: @John Are you _really_ hearing? Because I've already mentioned SSL.

Comment: Adnan there is no reason to talk like this.. If you find this unreasonable just don't bother. Thanks anyway

Comment: @John [Don't invent your own system.](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/25585/2264) Use SSL. It's cheaper, faster, safer, simpler. Your proposal offers no benefit.

Comment: Please see this article if you want to know why you have to use SSL: http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use HTTPS.

What you are doing will never be able to protect you against active attacks (MitM) since you don't have any trust anchors, and it is **very** likely that you will make some stupid mistake that will make it insecure.

Either way, you cannot encrypt more than a few hundred bytes directly with RSA. Thus, you will have to *securely* generate a random symmetric key (doing that properly in JavaScript is not easy), encrypt the data with it using a secure symmetric cipher (e.g. AES) in a secure block cipher mode, then encrypt the symmetric key with RSA. Learning how to do it "properly" will take you *much* more time than *really* doing it properly, and that is, configuring SSL.

Comment: Your answer is very informing, but the reason I was trying to do this, is to have a minimum security over my site requests to the server (which is a lot!). I think that SSL is somewhat heavy for the traffic I am expecting. Is there any way to do that without the random key? Or at least some other method faster than SSL?

Comment: The main load from SSL comes from the private key operation that has to be performed. SSL performs this at most once per connection establishment, with a connection being reused for multiple HTTP requests thanks to HTTP keep-alive, and the same SSL session may be reused across multiple connections thanks to SSL session handling. If you are going to call openssl_private_decrypt once for every page the user reads, it probably will be more expensive (load-wise) than SSL. BTW, SSL doesn't cause much load. A single core of my old laptop can handle 100 SSL handshakes per second.

Comment: @John for a page to be secure, you need to load every single piece of JS in a trusted way (including HTML which may contain scripts). The only way (that I know of/can imagine) to do that is to use SSL.

Comment: @John: One important note if you are worried about load with SSL - use a 2048 bit key. (Shorter is not allowed, longer will significantly increase load.)